# Allow only number with up to one decimal place in quasar input

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework

Is it possible using Quasar `q-input` to only allow integers and floating point number with only one decimal place? I tried using `:decimals="1"` and `step="0.1"` but it still allows me to type in any kind of number- so there is no form validation from what I see.

Is there a way, for example by using `:rules` param in `q-input` to allow only for integers and floats with one decimal point?

Comment: I think the validation only happens on submit, not on input. For real time input validation, you can either use Vuelidate or attach your custom event handler to the 'input' event and match the pattern `^\d+(\.\d)?$` (one or more digits followed optionally by a period and a single digit)

Comment: Or maybe you can make use of Masks: https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input#Mask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input#Example--Filling-the-mask-in-reverse), you could do something with the `mask` prop. For one decimal place, I believe it would be `mask="#.#"`

I've included a snippet below which is a modified version of [this](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101=https%3A%2F%2Fquasar.dev%2Fvue-components%2Finput) codepen.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      number: null
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.11.1/dist/quasar.umd.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="q-pa-md" style="max-width: 300px">
    <div class="q-gutter-md">
      <q-input
        filled
        v-model="number"
        label="1 decimals"
        mask="#.#"
        fill-mask="0"
        reverse-fill-mask
        hint="Mask: #.#"
        input-class="text-right"
      ></q-input>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  Number is {{number}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add

```
step="any"
```

and your input field can accept any decimals

```html
<q-input
  outlined
  type="number"
  v-model="formData.amount"
  label="Amount"
  lazy-rules
  step="any"
  :rules="[
    (val) =>
      (val !== null && val !== '') ||
      'Please type transaction amount',
  ]"
/>
```